# Returning a specific combination of alpha numeric characters

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a table that contains 1000s of rows with alpha numeric data such as this:

```
select id from status_table

id
--
N #AN54055Z / MATTHEW
345 IN  EH86963D  JP Verified o
C N # CV08705Z  PP CONF / A
UI 45 Ty
1548 47 CN #DW40205J  VERIFIED AF
N #-CT77535S
78 78Thi OK
584 C yu N #AV10045A/DONNA MO
AH28395U  VERIF BK MAH
yu YUyu789 56
```

There is a unique combination of alpha numeric characters I want to return in my results:

for example: alpha alpha numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric alpha

```
id
--
AN54055Z
EH86963D
CV08705Z
DW40205J
CT77535S
AV10045A
AH28395U
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the pattern with `PATINDEX` and then use this return value (the location where the pattern begins) as the start location in `SUBSTRING`. Since the pattern is static, so is the length for `SUBSTRING`

```
declare @t table (x varchar(256))

insert into @t values
('N #AN54055Z / MATTHEW'),
('345 IN  EH86963D  JP Verified o'),
('C N # CV08705Z  PP CONF / A'),
('UI 45 Ty'),
('1548 47 CN #DW40205J  VERIFIED AF'),
('N #-CT77535S'),
('78 78Thi OK'),
('584 C yu N #AV10045A/DONNA MO'),
('AH28395U  VERIF BK MAH'),
('yu YUyu789 56')

select d.* from(
    select 
        case 
            when PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]%',x) > 0
            then substring(x,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]%',x),8)
            else null
        end as id
    from @t) d
where d.id is not null
```

Comment: Well done. Note that you don't need to include ELSE NULL in a CASE statement; ELSE NULL is the default behavior.

Comment: Yea it's just habit to be explicit, ease of reading @AlanBurstein

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), also know as regex, which is a sort of macro language used to search for patterns in texts.

The following is a regular expression that matches 2 alpha characters uppercase followed by 5 numerics and then one alpha character.

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]
```

You can use `LIKE` in a `WHERE` statement to match patterns, for example
`WHERE MyField LIKE '%[A-Z]{2}%'`. On SQL Server 2008 and up you can use [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms188395.aspx) to find the index of the first match of a regular expression.

I can't run a test SQL right now, but I think something like this might work:

```
SELECT
    PATINDEX ( '%([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z])%', Id ) as TestPatIdx,
    CASE 
        WHEN PATINDEX ( '%([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z])%', Id ) > 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING( MyField, PATINDEX ( '%([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z])%' , Id ), 8 )
    END as TestResult,
    Id
FROM
    status_table
```

Comment: You can't use that this type of syntax with T-SQL: [A-Z]{2} instead you would need to do this [A-Z][A-Z].

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that, if this is data that you need to retrieve frequently you can create a computed column one your table and even index it if you want. Note my code and comments.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t;

CREATE TABLE #t
(
  -- the original column
  x varchar(256), 
  -- A computed column to extract that data ahead of time
  xx as        
  case 
    when PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]%',x) > 0
    then substring(x,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]%',x),8)
  end persisted
);

-- optional index if you search on that column frequently
-- NOTE That you indexes can speed up SELECT statements but will impact inserts/updates/deletes
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_t_xx ON #t(xx);

--declare @t table (x varchar(256))

insert into #t (x) values
('N #AN54055Z / MATTHEW'),
('345 IN  EH86963D  JP Verified o'),
('C N # CV08705Z  PP CONF / A'),
('UI 45 Ty'),
('1548 47 CN #DW40205J  VERIFIED AF'),
('N #-CT77535S'),
('78 78Thi OK'),
('584 C yu N #AV10045A/DONNA MO'),
('AH28395U  VERIF BK MAH'),
('yu YUyu789 56')

SELECT x, xx 
FROM #t;
```